# how to let htaccess work on every page

Tags: .htaccess

I think there is an easy solutions to my problem, but I'm quite the noob when it comes to htaccess. So I'm asking for help.

```
RewriteRule ^home/([\w-]+)/?$ home.php?lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This is my current code, and it works. But unfortunately, it only works on the page "home". And I want it to work on **all pages** of my URL. I've managed narrowing it down to this line:

```
RewriteRule ^/([\w-]+)/?$ ?lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

But it hasn't had any effect. So, could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the leading slash from rule's pattern

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ ?lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hmm, this actually seems to fix my problem. Thank you for helping me!